# Why draggable object jump on the random position jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I work with draggable and dropablle object, and I have issues with jumping objects on random place.

I have few dropablle areas, and dragable objects, for this I use script:

```
 $('.draggable-box').draggable();
```

For droping I use this script:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
        stop(e, ui) {
          
        },
    });

    $('.grid-item').droppable({
        accept: '.draggable',
        drop(e, ui) {
            ui.draggable.appendTo(this);
        },
    });
```

As you can see on attachment it is jumping to random place in the page.

[image]

One solution I found:

```
 $('.draggable').draggable({
        stop(e, ui) {
            $(this).css({
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
            });
        },
    });

    $('.grid-item').droppable({
        accept: '.draggable',
        drop(e, ui) {
            ui.draggable.appendTo(this);
        },
    });
```

But on this case it's stuck on one place, I try to change **css** values top left, it's no working. As I understood it's taking left and top from first storing box, and for this I get width of the box

```
var width = $(".box-legend").width();
var currentWithd = ui.position.left;
```

And try to minus from final position like this:

```
 $('.draggable').draggable({
            stop(e, ui) {
                $(this).css({ left: currentWithd - width})
            },
        });
```

But every time when I drag element it's jumping randomly, for now i tried and I have no idea how to fix :(

**So end result should be dragging element to the storage box, and this element stay on position not jumping.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].